# Writing a script that exports results depending on user input

Tags: export, scripting

Is there a way to tell `Export` to hold its arguments and just `Export`.

I tried to use `SetAttributes[Export,HoldRest];Attributes[Export]` and `HoldRest` now appears as one of its attributes but running the following still returns error since it is not stopping the evaluation of its arguments.

```
file=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"squares.m"}];
Export[file,If[Length[$ScriptCommandLine]==1,
    Print["No expressions were given to square."],

    args = Rest[$ScriptCommandLine];
 squares = Quiet @ Map[Replace[ToExpression[#], {$Failed:>ToString[#,InputForm]^2, x_ :> x^2}]&, args];
    MapThread[Print["The square of ", #1, " is ", #2, "."]&, {args, squares}]
],"Text"];
```

Comment: Why would you do all that *within* `Export`? Take the If outside of `Export` (e.g. `If[yourCondition, Export[file, yourstuff], elseStuff]`), and only apply `Export` when it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: Why don't you use WriteString? Alternatively, you can use Export["file",Unevaluated[ exp ]];

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to write the code so that everything is done in one `Export` expression is going about it wrong. I simply don't see any advance to it.

Here a script that I wrote that I believe does what you are trying to accomplish with simple, straightforward code. Besides working, it has the advantage of being easy to understand and debug.

---

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.11.3.0.app/Contents/MacOS/wolframscript

argv = Rest @ $ScriptCommandLine;
argc = Length @ argv;
If[argc == 0, Print["No expressions were given to square."]; Exit[]];

file = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "squares.txt"}];

Module[{vals, sqs, recds},
  vals = Select[(ToExpression /@ argv), NumberQ];
  sqs = vals^2;
  recds =
    MapThread[
      ToString[StringForm["The square of `1` is `2`.", #1, #2]] &, {vals, sqs}];
  Export[file, recds];
  Exit[]]
```

---

A Terminal session to test this script went as follows:

[image: session]

---

The file produced by the 1st execution of `squares` looked like this:

[image: file]